# How do I make a pipe operator with a UK layout but US Keyboard?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am in a course, we are using a VM to do Linux admin stuff. It's a Slackware 13.37 and because I'm geographically in the UK, it is using a UK layout (even though my system is set to US layout). I would like to either change it to the US layout (no option in preferences) or figure out where the hell the pipe key is. I've tried shift on every single key, and it doesn't show up. The "real" pipe key on my laptop does #/~ when in the VM. I know on UK keyboards it usually where the "Z" key would be on a US, but obviously that spot is taken. Alt (Left or Right) + Shift +  doesn't seem to have any effect and I don't have a numpad do the fancy ALT codes. I can't just copy/paste into it either.

P.S. I'm on a laptop so buying a UK keyboard isn't really a solution.

Thank you, have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will work for everyone, but Right ALT + the tilde key (key next to 1) works for me.

Comment: works! thanks, this saved me